# PHP/MySQL - updateing 2 tables in one request

Tags: php, sql, insert

I want to learn more about SQL and I'm wanting to update to tables;

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO `$table1`, `$table2` ($table1.DISPLAY_NAME, $table1.EMAIL_ACCOUNT, $table2.DISPLAY_NAME, $table2.EMAIL_ACCOUNT) values ('" . DISPLAY_NAME . "', '" . EMAIL_ADDRESS . "', '" . $get['rn'] . "', '" . $email . "')";
```

could some one point me in the right direction on how I would go about this? Current error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `contacts_ACT_Web_Designs` (contacts_E_Jackson.DISPLAY_NAME, contacts_E_Jackson' at line 1

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing your input. Doesn't PHP have the concept of parameterised queries? As it stands at the moment, I'd be more worried about SQL injection.

Comment: yes, im quite clued up on php just not so with sql. ( I have filters at the top of the page [ note $get not $_GET ] )

Comment: Just wondering,why would you want to insert the same information into two different tables within the same database?

Comment: setting up new contacts for an online instant messaging system. this will change when all is completed its just i built the IM that way. now im integrating it. so instead of back to fiddling, i will change it when i've finished. bit weird but i am weird!

Comment: looking into it further, i think i will change it all now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MуSQL you can insert records only into one table. At the same time, mysql_query() does not support multiple queries. So you should split your insertion into two requests and execute them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure a MySQL INSERT statement can insert into two tables?  I have never heard of being able to insert that way with any database.  Did you try two separate insert statements (one for each table)?

Comment: Ah ok. I just wanted to keep the amout of queries down as much as i can.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot insert into two tables at once, so you have to split your query into two separate ones. If you need them both to be inserted together (if one fails the other will not get inserted) then you can use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Basically you start a transaction run the queries if anything goes wrong you do a rollback if everything goes well you commit the transaction.

Also as far as I remember your engine must be InnoDB for transactions to be available.